# Shouldn't obfuscating remove signing of my dll?

Tags: c#, .net, dll, obfuscation, signing

I'm new to signing assemblies and am trying to understand this process. So I have a very simple WPF application that references a very simple DLL. The DLL is signed:
Preferences -> Signing -> Sign the assembly. Created a new *.snk file. And ok, everything works fine.

But I got confused that after obfuscating the DLL - despite warnings of ConfuserEx that the output might not be working as I didn't provide the key - the assembly works. The public token is the same than before the obfuscation. Shouldn't obfuscation remove/break the signing and while loading the obfuscated assembly shouldn't I get an error? Or is it correct? If so, why ConfuserEx warns me that the output might not be working?

Thanks.

Comment: Time to check the basics: is the file (you are using) actually obfuscated?

Comment: Yes, it is. I checked it with dotPeek.